# Skip first "n" keys in Amazon S3 ListObjectsV2

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I am able to list files from my bucket using

```
$contents = $this->s3client->listObjectsV2([
            'Bucket' => $this->bucket_name,
            'ContinuationToken' => $continuationToken,
            'Prefix' => $prefix,
            'Delimiter' => $delimiter
        ]);

return $contents;
```

By playing the `MaxKeys`, `ContinuationToken` and `StartAfter`, I am able to limit or get exactly the number of keys I need. However, I want to skip the first "n" keys. How can I achieve this?

E.g My bucket with `MaxKeys = 5` returns [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].

I need it such that I need to skip first 2 keys and `MaxKeys = 5` and returns [3, 4, 5].

I should be able to skip 2, 20, 200 or any number defined. `StartAfter` does not really help with it.

Comment: That's the neat part, you don't. Make a request for the number of keys you want to skip, throw away everything but the last key, and then make your request.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. In the end I need to make 2 requests and be charged for 2 requests every time?

Comment: Yes.  The API does not support a skip function, and if you need to make two requests, you will be charged for two requests.  If you're in a scenario where you need to make millions of list requests, consider making a [s3 metadata index](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/building-and-maintaining-an-amazon-s3-metadata-index-without-servers/)

Comment: That article is... _[chef's kiss]_. The summary of the first paragraph, and OP's problem in general is that with an object store if you don't already know the _exact_ key/keys that you want, you're going to have a _very_ bad time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do it the ugly way. Since every time I would have had to call the API Request, I made it fetch everything in the call and pushed to an array.

Then I discarded the number of items I did not need. That was the only way I came up with to do it with a single request instead of two request as mentioned in the comment above.

Yes it is a very ugly fix.